# What to pass as x-axis Max in Flot Time Series When using with Pan?

Tags: flot

I created Flot time series with pan functionality. Now i want my initial x-aixs hold only 10 data, when scrolled remaining will appear.

This is possible by adding max to x-axis.

In normal chart if i pass max: 10 then first 10 records will appear first and rest available when scrolled.

But in timeseries am not able to understand what to pass as max. Please give some solution.

```
                        xaxis: {
                                    mode: "time",
                                    timeformat: "%m/%d",
                                    tickSize: [1, "day"],  
                                    panRange:[min_date,max_date],
                                    max: ???,show: true

                                }
                                ,pan: {interactive: true}
```

Comment: Use the timestamp from the tenth data point.

Comment: Thank you! Raidri. It solved my issue.